# VBA Vlookup always returns #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I have two separate workbooks with data. I'm trying to find cell value matches using vlookup.

The column in Workbook one contains alphanumeric data as does the column being compared to in Workbook 2.

I have the following code to try and determine matches:

```
    Sub VirtualHostLookUp()

    'TO DO: iterate through all required workbooks and do lookup

    'open the workbook of interest
    'Workbooks.Open ("C:\Documents and Settings\1147808\My Documents\Pete\Data\tester.xlsx")

    'define this workbook
    Dim campus As Workbook
    Set campus = Workbooks(1)

    'define the lookup range - currently opens the first second open workbook
    Dim rng As range
    If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
        With Workbooks(2)
            Set rng = .Worksheets(2).UsedRange
        End With
    End If

    'initialise starting point
    Dim currRow, currCol As Integer
    currRow = 3
    currCol = 19

    'get first value to compare
    Dim currVal As Variant
    currVal = Cells(currRow, currCol).Value

    'find the number of rows in the column
    Dim totalRows As Long
    With campus.Worksheets(1)
        totalRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    campus.Activate

    'iterate through the rows
    For i = currRow To totalRows

        Dim cell As Variant
        Set cell = campus.Worksheets(1).Cells(currRow, currCol + 2)

        If currVal <> Empty Then
            cell.Value = Application.VLookup(currVal, rng, 2, False)

            If Not IsError(cell.Value) Then
                If cell.Value = Empty Then
                    cell.Value = "MATCH"
                End If
            End If
        End If

        'cell.Value = ""

        currRow = currRow + 1
        currVal = Cells(currRow, currCol).Value
    Next 
End Sub
```

I know there are matches between the two columns but the value "#N/A" is always returned and I cannot figure out why?

I have define the range as the UsedRange in Workbook2, this works and returns the correct values. The data to match against is in column 2 of Workbook 2.

What am I doing wrong?!?!

Comment: where is currVal defined?

Comment: above the for loop - have added the whole sub routine now (see above)

Comment: `currVal = Cells(currRow, currCol).Value`  You should always qualify `Cells()` with a specific worksheet reference. It's possible you're not getting the correct value for `currVal`

Comment: I have debugged and put a breakpoint there and it is being assigned the correct value!

Comment: is the column you trying to match to the leftmost column in the UsedRange?

Comment: No, the vlookup in the above passes 2 to indicate it's the second column in the range.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
For i = currRow To totalRows

    Dim cell As Variant
    Set cell = campus.Worksheets(1).Cells(currRow, currCol + 2)

    currVal=cell.Value

    If currVal <> Empty Then
        cell.Value = Application.VLookup(currVal, Workbooks(2).Sheets(2).UsedRange, 2, False)

        If Not IsError(cell.Value) Then
            If cell.Value = Empty Then
                cell.Value = "MATCH"
            End If
        End If
    End If

    currRow = currRow + 1
    currVal = Cells(currRow, currCol).Value
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

`currVal` is not initialized, you need to assign to it the proper value before you start to use it.

Comment: Sorry it is initialised above, I just didn't include it. have amended code.

Comment: N/A means not available. Maybe one of your cells don't have a value, so it is not available. Have you checked this?

Comment: I don't fully understand your point...if my cell has no value the n/a will be returned as there is no match...